# Combining string and returned value in label of ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, python-parser, labeling

Using ArcMap 10, I am trying to label features with the first character in from the field "label." I can get it to return the first character, but I want the label to be Div L, Div X, etc....

Here is my code:

```
    def FindLabel ( [label] ):
      L = [label] [:0]
      return L
      "Div " + L
```

How do I get that last line of code correctly in there?

Comment: `return "Div " + L`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything after the return value will not be run, as you have effectively told the function to stop running.

Change your return statement to be (as noted above by Bjorn):

```
return "Div " + L
```

As a side note, your index looks incorrectly formatted for Python. String splices are generally `[first index:last index]`, where the last index isn't included in the splice. If you leave out the first index, it defaults to zero; if you leave out the last index, it defaults to the end of the string. As written `[:0]` should give you the first character up to - but not including - the first character. In other words, it returns an empty string, as listed below.

```
>>> stringtest = "abcdefg"
>>> stringtest[:0]
''
```

Change your definition of L to `L = label[:1]` or `L = label[0]`

Comment: Hi smiller, since an index starts at 0, not 1, don't I want to have it [:0] ?

Comment: No, because whatever comes after the colon represents the index after you want to end. It's up to, but not including, that index. [1:5] would give you 1,2,3,4. [:15] would give 0 through 14. [:0] will give you nothing - just a blank.

Comment: Ohhh gotcha now. Thanks for that, I'll be keen to do that in the future.